# Aggregate soql query to retrieve all accounts with at least one opportunity and contact

Tags: apex, soql

I want to Write soql query to retrieve all accounts with at least one opportunity and contact. How can this be achieved with aggregrate soql?

> List accList = [select id, (select id,Amount from Opportunities where id =: AccounId and count(id)>=1 ), (SELECT Id FROM Contacts having id =: AccounId and count(id)>=1) from Account limit 10];
> system.debug(accList);

This is giving me errors

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account  WHERE Id IN (Select AccountId from Contact)  AND Id IN (Select AccountId from Opportunity)
```